# Authorization header present in the recording option but not replay

Tags: loadrunner

I have a custom request to upload a file which is failing with 401. When I compared the headers from record and replay I see that the authorization header is missing. How do i pass the authorization header to web custom request to upload different files. Below is the request headers from record and replay. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

*RECORDING REQUEST HEADERS:*

POST https://some.com/bd/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: some.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 6306
accept: application/json; charset=utf-8
Origin: https://some.com
authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjozMzg4NDQyOTYsImV4cCI6MTU3MDcxNTYyN30.5dT3cWmpPqNATMeSwSljb-QL1EWNzVPz69NAYndmI4A
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarySb4G73BxoA520nAP
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer: https://some.com/bd/batch
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cookie: auth_token=7a938f890e735aaef9c16d7979d99e96b0174c6e4846b78b7e33693a5d30ea54

------WebKitFormBoundarySb4G73BxoA520nAP
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="round_1.csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel

*REPLAY REQUEST HEADERS:*

:method: POST
:scheme: https
:path: /bd/upload
:authority: some.com
Content-Type:  multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------7d025e2b16b064e
Referer:  https://some.com/bd/batch
Cookie:  authToken=7a938f890e735aaef9c16d7979d99e96b0174c6e4846b78b7e33693a5d30ea54
Origin:  https://some.com
User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:  en-US,en;q=0.9
Accept:  */*
content-length: 6404

Comment: There is no simple solution to your question without understanding your application. I think all the information you need is on this page: https://community.microfocus.com/t5/LoadRunner-User-Discussions/Insert-OAuth-Token-in-a-web-add-header-in-Vugen-script/td-p/564948 but you should google possible solutions as well.

Comment: Common question:  Try this, https://ptfrontline.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/loadrunner-http-401-authentication/   The key is web_add_auto_header() with the appropriate field data.

Comment: The access_ token is sent as a json  response "access_token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJjcmVkZW50aWFsX2lkIjozMzg4NDQyOTYsImV4cCI6MTU3MDcxNTYyN30.5dT3cWmpPqNATMeSwSljb-QL1EWNzVPz69NAYndmI4A" when the user logs in. how do i extract this and send it as a header?

Comment: "... how do i extract this and send it as a header? – "   Correlation.   Covered in standard product training and in self paced tutorial available on Microfocus website where product is also downloaded.

Your management should only have you working in this space after training and with a mentor for a period of time.  If they are unwilling to engage in these minimal actions for your and the project's success, then you should assume you will get the blame for a failure to scale in production

Comment: This is something  I am learning on my own and not  for management or company!!!!!!!

Comment: Once you complete the correlation modules in the self paced training as well as review of the product documentation on the same subject, then you will be well prepared to handle the mechanics of dynamically generated data captured from server data flows and re-represented in client requests